# Bringing Google search results into Google Sheets using Regex instead of ImportXML

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am tracking keywords for Google search results in Google sheets.

When using importXML it looks like I am getting limited for the amount of XML I can import as I am getting #N/A in cells after a certain amount of use.

I found this custom code by @joshbradley that use of custom scripts to use regex instead of XPath which is meant to get around any limitation. Credit to Josh.

Essentially this goes in the script editor:

```
    function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      output = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'))[1];
    }
  }
  // Grace period to avoid call limit
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return unescapeHTML(output);
}
```

Then you call the script like this

```
=importRegex("https://example.com", "<title>(.*)<\/title>")
```

From here, I am trying to adapt the following code taken from GDS (Credit to Tara) that brings in Google search results but use the custom importregex approach above instead of importxml.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="& SUBSTITUTE(B$1, " ", "+") &"&pws=0&gl=UK&num=50", "//h3[@class='r']/a/@href[contains(.,'url')]"), "\/url\?q=(.+)&sa\b"))
```

**Update**

Here are two approaches I have tried (second has the array) but neither are working.

```
=importRegex("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="& SUBSTITUTE(B$1, " ", "+") &"&pws=0&gl=UK&num=50", "//h3[@class='r']/a/@href[contains(.,'url')]"), "\/url\?q=(.+)&sa\b"))

=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(importRegex("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="& SUBSTITUTE(B$1, " ", "+") &"&pws=0&gl=UK&num=50", "//h3[@class='r']/a/@href[contains(.,'url')]"), "\/url\?q=(.+)&sa\b"))
```

If it helps I have put a link to a Google sheet with the importregex script working [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hi44cyWBCNTjq37ZrTdpl85WWJn7OE98LV7bUU41_EE/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Where to did get stuck?

Comment: I have updated for you to show my best efforts : )